# SQL запрос. Связь записей при услови что строки нету

Tags: mysql, sql

Я хочу через SQL запрос вывести количесвто отзывов (`comments`) каждого продукта. Но дело в том что в таблице `comments` звписи появляется не при добавлении продукта, а при добавлении отзыва, то есть в таблице `comments` существуют не все товары.

Вот пример:

```
comments:
------------------------------------
|id |  product_id |  text          |
------------------------------------
|1  |      3      | fghgfhf        |
|2  |      6      | sadsasa        |
|3  |      6      | asdsas         |
------------------------------------

products:
-----------------------------------
|id |  product_name               |
-----------------------------------    
|3  |  asdsadsad                  |
|6  |  sdfdsfsdd                  |
|4  |  sffdgfdgd                  |
-----------------------------------
```

Мне нужно вывести количесво отзывов каждого товар, а если отзыва на товара нет (в данном случае это товар с `id = 4`), то вывести 0.

В итоге должно быть так:

```
comments_count |  product_id
----------------------------
       1       |       3
       2       |       6
       0       |       4
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы вывести все записи из таблицы1 вне зависимости от того, есть ли соответствующие связанные записи в таблице2, используют внешнее левое связывание: `FROM таблица1 LEFT JOIN таблица2 ON условие_связывания`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(c.id) as comments_count, 
       p.product_id 
from   products p 
left   join comments c 
on     p.product_id = c.product_id
group  by p.product_id
```